# how to send multiple instance with one ajax and receive in controller call in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Hello Guys i have a li from where i'm getting multiple employees. Right now i m sending employees one by one with `.each()` and i m getting multiple response with each call. here is my code

```
        var salary="";
        var designation ="";
        var employee ="";
        $(document).on('click', '.assign',function () { 
            salary = $(this).attr('salary');
            designation = $(this).attr('desg'); 
        }); 
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#employee-list li').each(function () {
                var employee = $(this).attr('value');   
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('salary_policy')}}',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                        employee_id : employee,
                        designation_id : designation,
                        salary : salary
                    },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data){

                alert(data.success);
                }
            });
        });   
    });
```

Question : How can i send all employees at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to add a class to the `li` of the employees who you 'assign'. Then you can create an array from their information and send that to your server in the AJAX request via the `data` property, something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.assign', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('assigned');
});

$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  var employeeData = $('#employee-list li.assigned').map(function() {
    return {
      employee_id: $(this).data('value'),
      designation_id: $(this).data('desg'),
      salary: $(this).data('salary'),
    }
  }).get();
  console.log(employeeData); // just for testing

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('salary_policy')}}",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data: employeeData,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.success);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
li.assigned {
  color: #C00;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="employee-list">
  <li data-value="1" data-salary="5" data-desg="foo">Lorem ipsum <button class="assign">Assign</button></li>
  <li data-value="2" data-salary="10" data-desg="bar">Dolor sit <button class="assign">Assign</button></li>
  <li data-value="3" data-salary="20" data-desg="fizz">Adipscing elit <button class="assign">Assign</button></li>
</ul>

<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Note the use of `data` attributes in the HTML. This is because creating non-standard attributes, such as `value`, `salary` and `desg`, will make the HTML invalid and can cause rendering or JS issues. If you want to store custom metadata in HTML always use a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: And how can i iterate this data in controller?

Comment: No idea as I've never worked with PHP or Laravel. I'd suggest starting a new question about that.